# Is there anyone can say why my CSS h1 is not working?

Tags: html, css

At first take my respect in Advance. I cant understand why my H1 is not working. Even the Dropdown is not working properly after hover. If Check you will have it. :(

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.main--nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.navbar ul li:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.drop--nav {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}

.drop--nav .dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.drop--nav:hover .dropdown {
  visibility: visible;
}

.main--para {
  position: relative;
}

.main--para p {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 180px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>position war</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="main--nav">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="drop--nav"><a href="">Servic</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Article</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Image</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="main--para">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam, dicta vitae? Officia repudiandae aspernatur, quo autem nisi iusto reprehenderit odio corrupti! Adipisci, sapiente iste. Quasi liquam sapiente, eaque laudantium odit et! Quas similique perspiciatis,
      culpa vero placeat, error nisi officiis incidunt iure, aspernatur eveniet est nostrum excepturi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="first--h1">
    <h1>i love bangladesh</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried a lot.. Even i am not sure with the position property that it can occur problem or not. Can you please help me?

Comment: what css is on the H1?

Comment: @gret b. Dear sir. I have use a H1 on my HTML portion. it is not working with this css. i did not add any class regarding to the h1 in the css.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What behavior are you expecting that you are not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The navigation menu is covering the H1.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.main--nav{
    display:flex;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.navbar ul li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:20px 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding:0 20px;

}
.navbar ul li:hover{
    background-color:aqua;
}
.drop--nav{
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
}
.drop--nav .dropdown{
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color:black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.drop--nav:hover .dropdown{
    visibility: visible;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="main--nav">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="drop--nav"><a href="">Servic</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Image</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main--para">
      <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam, dicta vitae? Officia repudiandae aspernatur, quo autem nisi iusto reprehenderit odio corrupti! Adipisci, sapiente  iste. Quasi liquam sapiente, eaque laudantium odit et! Quas similique perspiciatis, culpa vero placeat, error nisi officiis incidunt iure, aspernatur eveniet est nostrum excepturi.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="first--h1">
      <h1>i love bangladesh</h1>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. It works. But the H1 shows before the paragraph on the browser. But in the HTML this is after the the paragraph :(

Comment: Thank you sir. Its pleasure to me. it is working. thanks for your kind help. Take love.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `navbar` has a fixed position, the `h1` is underneath that element.

Consider adding a extra `content` div, that will contain both the `h1` and the text. Position this diff below the navbar to get the desired output:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.navbar{
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.main--nav{
    display:flex;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.navbar ul li{
    list-style:none;
    padding:20px 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    padding:0 20px;

}
.navbar ul li:hover{
    background-color:aqua;
}
.drop--nav{
    position:relative;
    background-color:black;
}
.drop--nav .dropdown{
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color:black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.drop--nav:hover .dropdown{
    visibility: visible;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="main--nav">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="drop--nav"><a href="">Servic</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Image</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main--para">
      <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam, dicta vitae? Officia repudiandae aspernatur, quo autem nisi iusto reprehenderit odio corrupti! Adipisci, sapiente  iste. Quasi liquam sapiente, eaque laudantium odit et! Quas similique perspiciatis, culpa vero placeat, error nisi officiis incidunt iure, aspernatur eveniet est nostrum excepturi.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="first--h1">
      <h1>i love bangladesh</h1>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. It works. But the H1 shows before the paragraph on the browser. But in the HTML this is after the the paragraph :(

Comment: Ok, I'll fix it

Comment: @ManuTheCoder Thank you sir. Its my pleasure that you help me.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMWW4IEL2JAT

Comment: Please edit your own answer @ManuTheCoder

Comment: I did edit my answer. for some reason this time it says:  It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members

Comment: @ManuTheCoder You've edited my answer, I've declined the edit.

Comment: @AbidAnowar Please check my edited answer, this should produce the desired output.

Comment: Thank you sir. Its pleasure to me. it is working. thanks for your kind help. Take love.